# How to export VTK in Mathematica

Tags: export

I would like to export VTK file in the Mathematica.

```
Clear["Global`*"] 
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
plotstyle = {Boxed -> False,
ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 0.7},
ImageSize -> 800};
size = 0.05;
coeff = 0.13;
numarrow2 = 6;
R2 = 1.5;
dtr2 = R2/6;
QV = 1;
x = r Cos[phi]; y = r Sin[ phi]; z = 0;
theta2 = \[Pi];
mx2 = coeff (Cos[QV phi] Sin[theta2]);
my2 = coeff (Sin[QV phi] Sin[theta2]);
mz2 = coeff (Cos[theta2]);
data2 = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, z}, {x + mx2, y + my2, z + mz2}}, {r, 0, R2, 
 dtr2}, {phi, 0, 2 \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/numarrow2}], 1];
Graphics3D[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Flatten[#][[6]]], Arrowheads[size], Arrow[Tube[#, size/4]]} & /@ data2, plotstyle]
Export["FIG1a.vtk", %]
```

But, I always get the same error.

```
Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the VTK format. >>
```

I researched the related mathematica's HELP but I cannot find the solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A simpler example that shows the problem:  `Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.05], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -0.13}}, .0125]]}] // 
 Export["test.vtk", #]`

Comment: This may be related to the fact that we can't seem to turn a `Tube` object into a `MeshRegion`:  `Graphics3D[Cone[]] // DiscretizeGraphics` and `Graphics3D[Cone[]] // Export["test.vtk", #] &` both work, but if you replace `Cone` with `Tube` then they don't work

Comment: @JasonB Thank you very much for your tips. Now, I can get a VTK file with `Cone`.

Comment: Please don't forget to point this shortcoming to WRI support .