# Exporting a vector field in VTK format

Tags: export

How could I export a `VectorPlot3D` object to VTK format?

I wish to export a vector field created by Mathematica in a VTK format to visualize in Paraview. All I have are coordinates and vectors defined at each co-ordinate.

I can't figure out how to use `Export` to do this. I keep getting the error message: `List cannot be exported to the VTK format`.

I am able to reproduce [this stack exchange post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113819/how-to-export-vtk-in-mathematica) which is very related but of course this involves glyphs that I don't want since I would like to visualize the flow in different ways.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Export` to `"VTK"` does not handle `Arrow`, not even `Arrow[Tube[..]]`; but it can handle `Tube` and `Cone`:

```
$maxlen = 0.08;
$aratio = 4.;
tubeArrow[p : {p1_, p2_}, radius_: 0.05] := Module[{len, v, r},
   v = p2 - p1;
   len = 0.5 Norm[v];
   len = Min[$maxlen, len];
   v = len*Normalize[v];
   r = len/$aratio;
   {Tube[{p1, p2 - v}, 0.5 r], Cone[{p2 - v, p2}, r]}
   ];

VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] /. 
 Arrow -> tubeArrow
```

[image]

```
Export["/tmp/foo.vtk", 
 foo = VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] /. 
   Arrow -> tubeArrow]
(*  "/tmp/foo.vtk"  *)

Import["/tmp/foo.vtk"]
```

[image]